# HTTP request is unauthorized... The authentication header received from the server was '' - During Visual Studio Build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, http-status-code-401

This is a very strange issue that started happening a couple of days ago after months of faultless operation. It's a 401 Unauthorized error, but the odd thing is that I get it during the build of a WCF service class in Visual Studio (i.e. highlight the .svc and hit F5 to run it in the WCF Test Client).

To compound the issue, it only happens to me. Other colleagues have verified this by grabbing the latest code from the source control (TFS) and repeating my steps, only for Visual Studio to build and run the service without any issues.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to 'remedies', suggestions so far have included edits of the IIS Express applicationhost.config file, deleting all source code from my machine and replacing it with fresh version from source control, the obvious multiple restarts of both my (Win7) machine and Visual Studio (2013), etc, none of which has made any difference.

I've seen a lot of similar instances of this error, most of which don't have a blank string for the 'authentication header received from the server', most things I've read online are where people have some value or another for that, and I've found it very difficult to find anyone that's experienced this exact issue (i.e. from a within VS, not using full IIS, during a standard build).

I'm starting tear my hair out as this project is now pretty much dead in the water until I can get it to build again, so any suggestions would be very gladly received...

Here's the exact error message I'm seeing, and a screen shot of it in context:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:53171/BlotterService.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost:53171/BlotterService.svc    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:53171/BlotterService.svc'.    The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.    The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost:53171/BlotterService.svc    There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:53171/BlotterService.svc'.    The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

[image]

EDIT:

My applicationhost.config looks like this:

```
<sectionGroup name="security">
    <section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="applicationDependencies" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <sectionGroup name="authentication">
            <section name="anonymousAuthentication" enabled="true" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="basicAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="clientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="digestAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <section name="authorization" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        <section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="dynamicIpSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="isapiCgiRestriction" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        <section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    </sectionGroup>
```

EDIT 2:

So I've just realised that IIS (as in the full version) had all of the ASP.NET features missing. Further checking of the "Windows features" in my Programs and Features panel revealed that my 'Application Development Features' section was all unticked. This was not the case beforehand, and I'm wondering what exactly I did to make this happen. I had to do an "iisreset" earlier in the week, perhaps that caused it...

[image]

Annoyingly though, even after reinstating these, and checking that IIS now showed them also, I am still experiencing the above issue :(

EDIT 3:

Web.config (minus logging blocks, db conn, and app settings) looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<!-- QA-->
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="false" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
    </diagnostics>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="Mba.Fed.BlotterService.BlotterServiceBehavior" name="Mba.Fed.BlotterService.BlotterService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILegacyBlotter" contract="Mba.Fed.BlotterService.ILegacyBlotter">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="MexHttpBinding_IMetadataExchange" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Mba.Fed.BlotterService.BlotterServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: This looks like IIS Express is no longer accepting "Anonymous" connections. I'd double-check your local IIS security settings and also the IUSR account to see whether it's disabled/locked out.

Comment: When you say "local IIS settings" are you talking about applicationhost.config? Or the full IIS UI?

Comment: The final cumulative effect on IIS would be a combination of both applicationhost.config and your service's web.config. Either one of those could have disabled "Anonymous" access through the .config files.

Comment: Could you post your web.config as well? Specifically the System.ServiceModel section?

Comment: I still have this issue, it affects every project on my machine. I just tried to add a service reference, from a brand new service I've created to an unrelated project, and I get the same error:

"Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:64455/DataService.svc'.
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''."

Comment: @Visionary    did you find the solution to this? I'm getting this error very rare.. 1 out of 200 requests.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem in the latest Google Chrome, but was surprised to find that things worked in IE 10.  I was able to login sometimes, but not others (such as refreshing a page).  The solution on my end ended up using the Properties (F4) of the project itself to enable Anonymous Authentication.